# Find the bounds of the following function

Tags: real-analysis

if $$f(x)={\sin x \over x}$$

Find the bounds of $f'(x)$

i get $$|f'(x)|=|{{x\cos x-\sin x}\over x^2}|\le|{\cos x\over x} |+|{\sin x \over x^2}|$$
How do i proceed further ?

***This is part of another question.**

Comment: I think Taylor series will be useful here.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** From the Taylor series, we have $$|f'(x)|=\left|\frac{\left(x-\frac{x^3}{2!}+\cdots\right)-\left(x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\cdots\right)}{x^2}\right|=\left|\frac{\left(-\frac{x^3}{2!}+\cdots\right)-\left(-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\cdots\right)}{x^2} \right|.$$Now, $$|f'(x)|=\left|\left(\frac{x}{2!}-\cdots\right)+\left(\frac{x}{3!}-\cdots\right)\right|.$$Can you take it from here?

Comment: so do we get a fixed bound here ? i think it will depend of $x$

Comment: You can find an upper bound that doesn't depend on $x$.

Comment: will differentiate it and equate to 0, if the second order derivative <0 then it gives maxima.

Comment: an increasing function

Comment: Sorry, wrong hint. Keep thinking for a little while; I have to leave. Others can help or I'll help when I return.

Comment: Sure , Thanks !!